# Copy Security Permissions from Program Files

Tags: security, windows-10

I want to have a copy of C:/Program Files/ in D:/Program Files, but just the folder with the security permissions, not the data, I want some programs to be installed on my SSD drive, and others on the HDD. But Program Files have some special security permissions and I can't easily recreate them.

Is it there a way to copy those security permissions?

Comment: Wouldn't WIM'ing `%ProgramFiles%` be more efficient?

Comment: What's WIM'ing?

Comment: Capturing a **W** [indows] **IM** [age] of `%ProgramFiles%`, which retains the ACL structure.  See everything after the [Imaging Section](https://superuser.com/a/1491014/529800).  Example commands are given with `/CaptureDir:"C:"`, change that to `/CaptureDir:"C:\Program Files"`

Comment: Hmm, never heard of it... But this would also copy all the contents of Program Files, which I don't want, so it will be a 2 operation anyway, right? Or I misunderstood what you meant by being effective.

Comment: You would specify any exclusions within a `wimscript.ini` file... this is only a paragraph into the Imaging section, so I'm assuming it wasn't read _(not helpful)_.

Your questions stated you maintain a copy of `%ProgramFiles%` in a secondary location... this implies to a reader you're maintaining 1:1 copy _(please update your wording if this is not the correct interpretation)_.  Without knowing why or how you're maintaining a copy of `%ProgramFiles%`, it's logical it would be a two-step operation, as the data has to be copied/captured & pasted/extracted. This is why capturing a WIM is ideal

Comment: Oh I see where the confusion came from, sorry, I am updating it

Comment: Just an FYI, you're going to have issues by installing programs to a non-sane directory (i.e. directories Windows expects programs to be installed to), and it's going to end up being more of a headache than it's worth.  It would make more sense to move your user directories to the HDD, not OS related directories.  To do so, right-click on your user data directories (Documents, Downloads, etc.) > properties > Location > enter new path > Move.

Comment: I already moved them, but some programs I want installed on the SSD and others on the HDD, for performance/size optimizations. I have done this on my last PC (Windows 7) and never had any issues, just this time I wanted to have the same security settings, which I didn't copy last time.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command under Power Shell with Administrator access did the trick:

```
Get-Acl -Path 'C:\Program Files' | Set-Acl -Path 'D:\Program Files'
```

Comment: Doesn't this only set the ACL for the directory `%ProgramFiles%` and not the data contained within it?

Comment: I don't want the data, just the ACL.... I want some programas to be installed on C: and others on D:

Comment: You misunderstood my question...Doesn't this command only set the ACL for `%ProgramFiles%` and not ACLs for the subdirectories and files contained within `%ProgramFiles%`?

Comment: I think there's a Recurse option, but since I am creating a new, empty folder, I don't have anything there to be set. I am expecting the ACLs will propagate the same as them do with `%ProgramFiles%`, as they are configured to do (I am almost certain I have seen this configuration on the ACLs)